# How to get focused window handler

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I have a `WPF` custom virtual keyboard application. I need to host this WPF application as standalone and user should be able to use this to enter values for any window application.

How to get the current focused application window? ex: notepad, notepad++ or any other window applications which takes in input.

I have tried below code to get the current active window, but it returns the WPF virtual keyboard application itself since it is also in active state

```
var window = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.IsActive);
```

The below code works fine however, this requires `windowname` as `param` to set the `foregroundwindow`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window{
    
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);    
    
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    SetForegroundWindow(FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Untitled - Notepad"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current active window handle, you could use [GetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow) from the user32.dll.

In C# it should look something like

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

Or in case your application window will be the active window, you could use [GetWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindow)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, GetWindow_Cmd uCmd);

enum GetWindow_Cmd : uint {
    GW_HWNDFIRST = 0,
    GW_HWNDLAST = 1,
    GW_HWNDNEXT = 2,
    GW_HWNDPREV = 3,
    GW_OWNER = 4,
    GW_CHILD = 5,
    GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
}
```

So you could pass your own window handle as first argument and `GW_HWNDNEXT` as second. As a result you get the handle for the window that is below your current window.

**EDIT**

As IInspectable mentioned, the above won't work within an WPF application.

But you could try using the following using [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows):

```
// Get own hWnd
WindowInteropHelper windowHwnd = new(this);
IntPtr ownHwnd = windowHwnd.Handle;

// Find target hWnd
IntPtr targetHWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
NativeMethods.EnumWindows((hWnd, lParam) => 
{
  if (hWnd == ownHwnd) { return true; } // Ignore own window
  if (!NativeMethods.IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) { return true; } // Ignore hidden windows
  if (GetClassName(hWnd).Equals("Shell_TrayWnd", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) { return true; } // Ignore taskbar window
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetWindowTitle(hWnd))) { return true; } // Ignore windows without a title
  targetHWnd = hWnd; // Found target hWnd
  return false; // Stop iterating
}, IntPtr.Zero);

// Used functions

private string GetWindowTitle(IntPtr hWnd)
{
  int textLength = NativeMethods.GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
  StringBuilder sb = new(textLength + 1);
  NativeMethods.GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
  return sb.ToString();
}

private string GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new(256);
  NativeMethods.GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
  return sb.ToString().Trim();
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);
    internal delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);
}
```

**Edit 2**

To ensure the WPF hWnd is created, you could use [WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.ensurehandle?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-interop-windowinterophelper-ensurehandle) method instead of the `Handle` property. This is important if the WPF window has not been displayed yet.

Comment: WPF employs window-less controls. Calling `GetWindow` doesn't get you anywhere.

Comment: @IInspectable The mentioned application has a window and the goal is to find the topmost active HWND which is not part of the application. So why should `GetWindow` not be the right method?

Comment: `GetWindow` navigates window *hierarchies*. A WPF application doesn't have a window hierarchy consisting of native windows. Feel free to verify applicability of your proposed solution.

Comment: @Gabriel i tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @IInspectable i read your comments, `WPF application doesn't have a window hierarchy` so does it mean that we can't get track of focused windows?.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for the explanation. I have added an alternative way, even if it is a bit hacky.

Comment: May I convince you to **verify** that your proposed solutions actually work? If there is no native window (which happens to be the case for WPF) then there is no `HWND` either. Since your alternative solution solely relies on API calls that require an `HWND` it cannot work either...

Comment: @IInspectable I did. The posted code is from a small WPF test app I wrote. For this use case the [WindowInteropHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is used.